# Adding horizontal scrollbar using CupertinoScrollbar - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, scrollview, scrollbar, flutter-web

I am wanting to apply a draggable horizontal and vertical scrollbar to our flutter web app using CupertinoScrollbar and SingleChildScrollView. Scrolling horizontally and vertically does seem to work but when you click on the horizontal scrollbar and drag it, its irresponsive . This is what I have tried so far. Any help would be appreciated !

```
CupertinoScrollbar(
                thickness: 20.0,
                thicknessWhileDragging: 15.0,
                isAlwaysShown: true,
                controller: scrollController,
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  controller: scrollController,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  child: CupertinoScrollbar(
                    thickness: 20.0,
                    thicknessWhileDragging: 15.0,
                    isAlwaysShown: true,
                    controller: scrollController2,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      controller: scrollController2,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      child: Row(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                    height: 174,
                                    width: 1920,
                                    child: TopMenuBarDesktopV2(
                                        centerWidth: centerWidth,
                                        mainScrollController:
                                            scrollController)),
                                Container(
                                  width: 1920,
                                  height: 1015,
                                  color: AutColors.mediumPurple,
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 45),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Spacer(),
                                      Container(
                                        width: widget.contentWidth,
                                        child: widget.content,
                                      ),
                                      Spacer()
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                    width: screenWidth,
                                    height: 240,
                                    child: Footer(centerWidth)),
                              ],
                            ),
                            // ),
                            // ),
                          ]),
                    ),
                  )
```

[image]

Comment: need to see output can post image what do you want ??

Comment: @JanviPatel  So I have both vertical and horizontal bars showing and partially working. The only thing that isn't working is the horizontal bar, when you click on the horizontal bar and drag it to the right , it doesn't move, instead it triggers the vertical scrollbar

Comment: It might be that you have used horizontal scroll bar inside vertical scroll bar

Comment: I have tried using only a horizontal scrollbar yet it still wouldn't work